# Subtracting inputed data in Swift

Tags: swift

Good afternoon,

I am having an issue trying to figure out how I take data that was inputed from a textfield and use that data later on in the code. I have attached my code and hopefully I would be able to get some help.

```
@IBAction func wEnter(sender: AnyObject) {

        let number1 = Double(waistText1?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let number2 = Double(waistText2?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let number3 = Double(waistText3?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let number4 = Double(neckText1?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let number5 = Double(neckText2?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        let number6 = Double(neckText3?.text ?? "") ?? 0
        wavgText.text = String(round(10 * (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3) / 10 ) + " inches"
        navgText.text = String((number4 + number5 + number6) / 3) + " inches"


        let number7 = Double(wavgText.text! )
        let number8 = Double(navgText.text! )

        soldBF.text = String(number7 - number8) + "%"


}
```

Everything seems to be working correctly except for when i try to subtract number7 from number 8. Am i missing something?

if you need anymore details please let me know

Comment: Time to debug: Add a breakpoint, single step through in the debugger inspecting the values as you go. Or go old school with print() statements of the values.

Comment: `Double("N inches")` is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better if you switch the order of operations:

```
    let number7 = round(10 * (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3) / 10
    let number8 = (number4 + number5 + number6) / 3

    wavgText.text = "\(number7) inches"
    navgText.text = "\(number8) inches"
    soldBF.text   = "\(number7 - number8)%"
```

Then you can see what the problem is.